# Can I use Whatsapp / take backup on phone A while having associated SIM card inserted in Phone B?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

**Problem Statement**

Phone A (Nexus 6P) cannot detect mobile networks due to some issue and hence cannot receive WhatsApp verification SMS. This makes WhatsApp on Phone A unusable. Phone B (Samsung J7 Prime) is OK in all aspects.

**Proposed Idea**

1. Use SIM of Phone A in Phone B
2. Log in to WhatsApp on phone A. Receives verification SMS on Phone B and access WhatsApp on Phone A using that verification SMS
3. Take a WhatsApp backup on Phone A and send it to Google Drive
4. Then log in to WhatsApp on Phone B and restore the backup on Phone B
5. Finally, start using WhatsApp on Phone B

Will the proposed idea work? Will it destroy my WhatsApp chat history?

Comment: Hi, yes, it will work. If there is existing chat history on the device associated with the same WhatsApp number, then it should be retained with no issues.